# jQuery: Animating a sequence images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation

So for the last few *days* I am struggling to get this to work. Although some SO members have already helped me a lot, I still feel that I am on the wrong track because I just can't get this to work.

**Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxLu2/2/).**

Basically, I want to dynamically add/remove the class `.show` to the images inside `.container` depending on the scroll position. In the example posted I am just attempting this for a down-scroll.
If you scroll really light and slowly you see that it actually works, but much too fast - that's the problem.
My idea is to define something like a threshold that has to be scrolled before something happens, but somehow I don't get the desired result.

Also, the `scroll` event seems to be triggered not regular in browser, so I have no idea how to get a smooth movement/transition with it. I already looked at some example code from tutorials and there it always seems to work! Why not with my example? Has it something to do with my CSS?

Please help my, I am really frustrated right now.

For example take [that tutorial page](http://fraser-hart.co.uk/demos/sprite-animation/) and take a look at the source. There is a variable called `ScrollCount` which is incremented for every time the function ran. When `ScrollCount` reaches 3, some animation stuff is done and `ScrollCount` is reset to 1. That way, according to the comments, every third pixel scrolled the bird's wings change.

But according to the observations with my code, this can't be true, because the `scroll` event which triggers the function seems to fire more or less at random - the faster you scroll the more pixels are "skipped" - at least with my code, so something has to be wrong.

Comment: 403 Forbidden on your imgur references...

Comment: @landons Woops, sorry! Don't know what happened there. Updated the links, should be fine now.

Comment: @landons Strange. I changed the hoster, hopefully it's fine now.

Comment: If code from tutorials work, and yours doesn't, there's clearly something different between them. Showing us one of the working tutorials will go a long way to helping us understand exactly what you're trying to do, which will turn the exercise into a simple "spot the difference" instead of a broader "spot what's wrong".

Comment: @Snixtor Ok I see, I've added an example.

Comment: Have you looked at the javascript used on the animation demo site you linked? It's working quite differently to what you're trying to accomplish. It calculates the position of "sprites" based on the absolute scroll position. Whereas you're changing to a different frame depending on whether the last scroll action was up or down, but doesn't check the absolute scroll position. This will have **very** different results.

Comment: On closer examination, I see the example uses both the quantity of scroll events and absolute scroll position to determine the animation behaviour. This strikes me as something that would produce inconsistent results, more details in my answer below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tying animation elements to the quantity of scroll events is going to give inconsistent results. On the sample [page you linked](http://fraser-hart.co.uk/demos/sprite-animation/), the animation is tied to both absolute scroll position and quantity of scroll events, which can give some strange results.

There's so many different ways to scroll a view, and all of them will produce a different numbers of scroll events and scroll distances.

- Mouse wheel (affected by system mouse settings, resolution of mouse)
- Keyboard up and down keys (affected by system key repeat rates)
- Page up and down (possibly affected by some other settings?)
- Dragging the scroll bar (affected by all sorts of things)

And then all of these may well behave differently based on the browser.

In short? Tying animation to the *quantity* of scroll events sounds like a bad idea to me. Instead, why not just tie it to the scroll position?

```
function animateHorse() {
    var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    var imageIndex = Math.round(currentScrollPosition / scrollResolution);

    if (imageIndex >= pictureCount) {
        imageIndex = pictureCount - 1; // Select last image
    }

    $("#container img").hide();
    $("#container img").eq(imageIndex).show();
}
```

[And here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PpCU5/)

Comment: Yes I've ran into the inconsistencies and they made me mad ha! So I see why your code is much better, thank you! I didn't even know that you can call a function before its defined - does this technique has a special name or something?

Comment: There's nothing special about calling a function before its definition, just that some languages won't let you do it.

Comment: This is such a perfect solution. I'd love to find a solution that delays the animation to when a div is revealed or in the viewport. No matter what I do, the animation always begins when I scroll at the top, but what if I don't want the animation to work until a div is revealed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is The Working Demo And You Can See The Horse Animation...

```js
onload = function startAnimation() {
  var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
  var frameCount = frames.length;
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
    frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
#animation img {
  display: none;
}
#animation img:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation">
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/t57meexkb/horse_1.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/i86apnasr/horse_2.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/6kc8v3lnv/horse_3.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/w4ej1j71n/horse_4.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/ddclrdch7/horse_5.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/nbxkdulwr/horse_6.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/phrv8cpd7/horse_7.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/n1un88wob/horse_8.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/9yz0oz6gb/horse_9.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/6gn0sl5kb/horse_10.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/vnxwsu8ob/horse_11.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/bhuetyd0r/horse_12.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/imc82zka3/horse_13.png" class="animated" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/auvi4fg4r/horse_14.png" class="animated" />
</div>
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/u20yvyp9/

Comment: How can i stop this when animation is complete?